# Parse a log4j log file

Tags: file, parsing, log4j, logging

We have several applications that use log4j for logging. I need to get a log4j parser working so we can combine multiple log files and run automated analysis on them. I'm not looking to reinvent the wheel, so can someone point me to a decent pre-existing parser? I do have the log4j conversion pattern if that helps.

If not, I'll have to roll our own.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I didn't realize that Log4J ships with an XML appender.

Solution was: specify an XML appender in the logging configuration file, include that output XML file as an entity into a well formed XML file, then parse the XML using your favorite technique.

The other methods had the following limitations:

- [Apache Chainsaw](https://logging.apache.org/chainsaw/) - not automated enough
- jdbc - poor performance in a high performance distributed app

Answer (score 3):

You can use [OtrosLogViewer](http://code.google.com/p/otroslogviewer/) with [batch processing](http://code.google.com/p/otroslogviewer/wiki/BatchProcessing). You have to:

1. Define you log format, you can use [Log4j pattern layout parser](http://code.google.com/p/otroslogviewer/wiki/Log4jPatternLayout) or [Log4j XmlLayout](http://code.google.com/p/otroslogviewer/wiki/IncludedLogParsers)
2. Create java class that implements [LogDataParsedListener](http://otroslogviewer.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/OtrosLogViewer-app/src/main/java/pl/otros/logview/batch/LogDataParsedListener.java). Method  public void logDataParsed(LogData data, BatchProcessingContext context) will be called on every parsed log event.
3. Create jar
4. Run OtrosLogViewer with specifying your log processing jar, LogDataParsedListener implementation and log files.

Comment: There are some problems writting  working configuration which can parse log4j xnl.

Comment: OLV cannot be automated. Use xml Parser utility instead.

Comment: I think OLV  solutuion has big verhead

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is called [SawMill](http://www.sawmill.net/formats/log4j.html), or **something like it**.

Answer (score 1):

Log4j log files aren't really suitable for parsing, they're too complex and unstructured. There are third party tools that can do it, I believe (e.g. Sawmill).

If you need to perform automated, custom analysis of the logs, you should consider logging to a database, and analysing that. JDBC ships with the [`JdbcAppender`](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/jdbc/JDBCAppender.html) which appends all messages to a database of your choice, but it has performance implications, and it's a bit flaky. There are other, similar, alternatives on the interweb, though (like [this one](http://www.dankomannhaupt.de/projects/index.html)).

Answer (score 0):

`xmlstarlet` is an excellent choice for parsing log4j logs when automation is a priority. There are several key reasons why it's one of the best suitable utilities for this task:

1. **XPath Support:** `xmlstarlet` supports XPath, which is a powerful and flexible language for navigating and querying XML documents. In the context of log4j logs, this allows you to target specific elements and attributes with precision.
2. **Command-Line Interface:** It operates via the command line, making it easy to integrate into scripts and automated workflows. This is invaluable for processing log files in a batch or scheduled manner.
3. **Modifications and Transformations:** Beyond just parsing, `xmlstarlet` can be used to make changes to XML documents. In log4j logs, this means you can edit or reformat log entries, making it a versatile tool for log file analysis and maintenance.
4. **Compatibility:** It's available on various platforms, including Windows, Linux, and macOS, making it suitable for a wide range of environments.
5. **Well-Documented:** `xmlstarlet` has a comprehensive and well-documented set of features, which simplifies the learning curve for those who are new to it. Documentation is crucial when automation is involved, as it ensures clear guidance for scripting.
6. **Community and Support:** Being a widely-used utility, `xmlstarlet` has an active community and plenty of online resources. If you run into issues or need assistance with automation scripts, you're likely to find the help you need.

For parsing log4j logs, `xmlstarlet` is particularly beneficial because log4j logs are often formatted as XML. With its features, automation becomes straightforward, enabling tasks like log aggregation, filtering, and alerting to be efficiently managed.

Ultimately, if you're looking for a dependable and robust solution for parsing log4j logs and need automation capabilities, `xmlstarlet` should be at the top of your list.

Answer (score -1):

You -can- use Log4j's Chainsaw V2 to process the various log files and collect them into one table, and either output those events as xml or use Chainsaw's built-in expression-based  filtering, searching & colorizing support to slice & dice the logs.

Steps:
 - Start Chainsaw V2
 - Create a chainsaw configuration file by copying the example configuration file available from the Welcome tab - define one LogFilePatternReceiver 'plugin' entry for each log file that you want to process
 - Start Chainsaw with that configuration
 - Each log file will end up as a separate tab in the UI
 - Pause the chainsaw-log tab and clear the events from that tab
 - Create a new tab which aggregates the events from the various tabs by going to the 'view, crate custom expression logpanel' menu item and enter 'level >= DEBUG' in the box.  It will create a new tab containing events from all of the tabs with level >= debug (which is why you cleared the chainsaw-log tab).

You can get an overview of the expression syntax used to filter, colorize and search from the tutorial (available from the Help menu).

If you don't want to use Chainsaw, you can do something similar - start a simple app that doesn't log but loads a log4j.xml config file with the 'plugin' entries you defined for the Chainsaw configuration, but also define a FileAppender with an xmllayout - all of the events received by the 'receivers' will be sent to the single appender.

Comment: This tool is obsolete