# How to reduce the verbosity of Spark's runtime output?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

How to reduce the amount of trace info the Spark runtime produces?

The default is too verbose,

How to turn off it, and turn on it when I need.

Thanks

#### Verbose mode

```
scala> val la = sc.parallelize(List(12,4,5,3,4,4,6,781))
scala> la.collect
15/01/28 09:57:24 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: collect at <console>:15
15/01/28 09:57:24 INFO DAGScheduler: Got job 3 (collect at <console>:15) with 1 output 
...
15/01/28 09:57:24 INFO Executor: Running task 0.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 3)
15/01/28 09:57:24 INFO Executor: Finished task 0.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 3). 626 bytes result sent to driver
15/01/28 09:57:24 INFO DAGScheduler: Stage 3 (collect at <console>:15) finished in 0.002 s
15/01/28 09:57:24 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 3 finished: collect at <console>:15, took 0.020061 s
res5: Array[Int] = Array(12, 4, 5, 3, 4, 4, 6, 781)
```

#### Silent mode(expected)

```
scala> val la = sc.parallelize(List(12,4,5,3,4,4,6,781))
scala> la.collect
res5: Array[Int] = Array(12, 4, 5, 3, 4, 4, 6, 781)
```

Comment: This isn't the scala REPL that's printing that, but the Spark runtime. So you need to be looking at options for controlling Spark's output.

Comment: I think this question has more to do with Spark and the logger used by spark than with Scala. So spark uses log4j for loggin, which can be configured in "SPARK_HOME/conf/log4j.properties.template" . Change the settings corresponding to console howerver you want. More specifically change first line to "log4j.rootCategory=ERROR, console" .

Answer (score 42, accepted):

quoting from '[Learning Spark](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449358624)' book.

> You may find the logging statements that get printed in the shell
>   distracting. You can control the verbosity of the logging. To do this,
>   you can create a file in the conf directory called **log4j.properties**.
>   The Spark developers already include a template for this file called
>   **log4j.properties.template**. To make the logging less verbose, make a
>   copy of **conf/log4j.properties.template** called **conf/log4j.properties**
>   and find the following line:
>
> `log4j.rootCategory=INFO, console`
>
> Then
>   lower the log level so that we only show WARN message and above by
>   changing it to the following:
>
> `log4j.rootCategory=WARN, console`
>
> When
>   you re-open the shell, you should see less output.

Answer (score 79):

## Spark 1.4.1

```
sc.setLogLevel("WARN")
```

From comments in source code:

> Valid log levels include: ALL, DEBUG, ERROR, FATAL, INFO, OFF, TRACE, WARN

## Spark 2.x - 2.3.1

`sparkSession.sparkContext().setLogLevel("WARN")`

## Spark 2.3.2

`sparkSession.sparkContext.setLogLevel("WARN")`

Comment: works great in 1.6.1! I had trouble for Spark to read properties from my $SPARK_HOME/conf directory, but I like setting properties on runtime even better - although you still receive INFOs during SparkContext initialization, but from then it's how you set it. great when collaborating to have the same config.

Comment: What is the `sc` variable  ?

Comment: @Moebius That would be your instance of SparkContext

Comment: In Spark 2.x you need to set sparkSession.sparkContext().setLogLevel("WARN")

Answer (score 9):

## Logging configuration at the Spark app level

With this approach **no need of code change in cluster** for a spark application.

- Let's create a new file **log4j.properties** from **log4j.properties.template**.
- Then change verbosity with `log4j.rootCategory` property.
- Say, we need to check **ERROR**s of given jar then, `log4j.rootCategory=ERROR, console`

#### Spark submit command would be

```
spark-submit \
    ... #Other spark props goes here    
    --files prop/file/location \
    --conf 'spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=prop/file/location' \
    --conf 'spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=prop/file/location' \
    jar/location \
    [application arguments]
```

Now you would see only the logs which are ERROR categorised.

---

### Plain Log4j way wo Spark(but needs code change)

Set Logging **OFF** for packages `org` and `akka`

```
import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}

Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ERROR)
Logger.getLogger("akka").setLevel(Level.ERROR)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are invoking a command from a shell, there is [a lot you can do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2327073/parse-a-log4j-log-file) without changing any configurations. That is by design.

Below are a couple of Unix examples using pipes, but you could do similar filters in other environments.

### To completely silence the log (at your own risk)

Pipe stderr to `/dev/null`, i.e.:

`run-example org.apache.spark.examples.streaming.NetworkWordCount localhost 9999 2> /dev/null`

### To ignore `INFO` messages

`run-example org.apache.spark.examples.streaming.NetworkWordCount localhost 9999 | awk '{if ($3 != "INFO") print $0}'`